# Color band on SURF descriptors

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, surf

I'm reading [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6847226) paper for obtaining better VLAD descriptors. The main difference is the use of the so called **CSURF** which is (quoting the paper):

> In order to extract CSURF, the image
>   is first transformed to grayscale and
>   interest points are computed using the
>   standard SURF algorithm. Then, instead
>   of computing the SURF descriptor of
>   each interest point on the intensity
>   channel, CSURF computes three SURF
>   descriptors, one on each color band.

How could I implement this in OpenCV? All the descriptors that I've seen so far (SIFT, SURF, ETC) are computed on the gray scale, how could I use SURF to describe keypoints based on one color band (Red, Green or Blue)?

**UPDATE: IS THIS SOLUTION CORRECT?**

```
Mat img = imread( src, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
Mat grey;
cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

int minHessian = 400;
Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( minHessian );
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

detector->detect( grey, keypoints );

vector<Mat> spl;
Mat blueDesc, greenDesc, redDesc;
split(img,spl);
detector->detectAndCompute( spl[0], Mat(), keypoints, blueDesc, true);
detector->detectAndCompute( spl[1], Mat(), keypoints, greenDesc, true);
detector->detectAndCompute( spl[2], Mat(), keypoints, redDesc, true);
```

Comment: You can use `cv::split` to get each channel. Each channel is a `Mat1b` (type `CV_8UC1`), so you can then compute the SIFT descriptor on each one of your channels separately, given the SIFT keypoints extracted on the grayscale image.

Comment: @Miki Please look at the **UPDATE** section

Comment: If `src` is the original color image, and `img_1` is its grayscale, then yes, it's correct. You can load `src` as IMREAD_COLOR, and use `cvtColor(..., COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` to get the grayscale one

Comment: `imread(src, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);` and `split(src,spl);` -- that doesn't look right... are you trying to split the string containing the image file path?

Comment: Ok thank you @DanMašek for your comment, not it should be fixed

Comment: Thank you @Miki, not it should be fixed